# How to get correct mean values after applying Fourier Transform on Accelerometer data iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fft, accelerometer, accelerate-framework

I am using `Accelerate framework` to apply FFT on accelerometer data, code below:

```
         //Set up
                FFTSetup fft_weights;
                DSPSplitComplex inputDataSplitComplex;
                Float32 *outMagnitudes;
                UInt32  mAccelFFTLength;
                UInt32 log2n;
                UInt32 fftFrameSize;

                Step 1:
                    -(void)initializeFFtSetUP
                    {
                        fftFrameSize = fftsize; //256
                        mAccelFFTLength = fftFrameSize/2; //128
                        log2n = log2f(fftFrameSize/2)+1;

                    inputDataSplitComplex.realp = (Float32 *)calloc(mAccelFFTLength,sizeof(Float32));

                        inputDataSplitComplex.imagp = (Float32 *)calloc(mAccelFFTLength,sizeof(Float32));

                        fft_weights = vDSP_create_fftsetup(log2n, kFFTRadix2);
                        outMagnitudes = (Float32 *)calloc(mAccelFFTLength,sizeof(Float32));

                    }


            Step 2:

            - (Float32)calculateFastFourierTransform
            {
              //accelDataArray is an NSMutableArray of accelerometer data values 'userAcceleration.x'  from CMDeviceMotionManager
                for (NSUInteger currenIndex = 0; currenIndex < mAccelFFTLength; currenIndex++)
                {
                    inputDataSplitComplex.realp[currenIndex] = (Float32)[[accelDataArray objectAtIndex:currenIndex]floatValue];
                    inputDataSplitComplex.imagp[currenIndex] = 0.0f;
                }
               vDSP_fft_zrip(fft_weights, &inputDataSplitComplex, 1, log2n, kFFTDirection_Forward);

                inputDataSplitComplex.realp[0] = 0.0;
                inputDataSplitComplex.imagp[0] = 0.0;

                Float32 meanVal = 0.0;
                Float32 fftMax = 0.0;

                // Get magnitudes
                vDSP_zvmags(&inputDataSplitComplex, 1, outMagnitudes, 1, mAccelFFTLength);
                vDSP_vsq(outMagnitudes, 1, outMagnitudes, 1, mAccelFFTLength);//square
                vDSP_meanv(outMagnitudes, 1, &meanVal, mAccelFFTLength);

                return sqrtf(meanVal);
            }
```

Problem: When the device is stable values are ok however when I put the device to acceleration, the values (meanVal) goes in thousands ex:5248, 64000.I am not able to find what exactly is wrong in the code or FFT setup. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem:
'vDSP_zvmags' produces the square of magnitudes of the complex vector, hence the next line 'vDSP_vsq' was not required. I was computing the square twice hence the results were large values.